# Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOrderedSet

Tags: iphone, ios

One of our iPhones crashes with this in it's log messages (the rest of the iPhones are fine):
The iPhone's version is 4.3.3 but I've tried with 4.3 simulator as well and it worked (and it's working with other 5.0.1 phones)

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOrderedSet
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/CB7770DB-8FE2-44E0-AFC9-B1961E5D0F60/Toplamax.app/Toplamax
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/CB7770DB-8FE2-44E0-AFC9-B1961E5D0F60/Toplamax.app/Toplamax
  Dyld Version: 191.3
```

Thanks, David

Comment: NSOrderedSet is only available on iOS 5+

Comment: The simulator does not work the same as a device, Thus checking if something work in the simulator does not mean it will work on the device.

Comment: I have the same probleam but with a twist: the app works ifi installed as a debug build by Xcode. The app dos not use NSOrderedSet, nor CoreData "Ordered" relationship attribute; not sure about RestKit. Either way I think this goes deeper thatn 4.x vs 5.x difference

Comment: Same as Mihai. There was a reference to NSOrderedSet in RestKit that caused a crash when launching the app when downloaded from the app store, but when installed using XCode, there was no problem. Being able to run in the simulator makes sense but how would the code run in a device running version 4.x but crash when the same app is downloaded from the App Store. Any ideas for a better to debug these types of problems before the reach a release?